# Google Drive not recognizing wi-fi connection

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, google-drive

So, Google Drive for Android decided to deny me access to my files, saying I've no connection. I do have a good connection as I am able to watch videos and check out forums in the mean time.

The thing is, the moment I connect to a friend's WiFi, it works. If I go back to my own WiFi, Google Drive suddenly stops working.

Again, I have a perfectly good connection with everything else but Google Drive. What on earth is going on here?

Comment: Try clearing the cache of drive app and then connecting to WiFi